# How can I install Xcode 4.1 when 4.2 is already out and everywhere?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, osx-lion

I've recently upgraded to OS X Lion and Xcode 4.2, which however seems to cause a lot of problems with Ruby.

What I need to do is install 4.1 instead of the currently 4.2, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. App Store and the official download page already offers only 4.2.

**Is there any way I can get back to 4.1?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find old versions of xcode here. Make sure to install it in a different directory.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Answer (score 0):

You find older versions of Xcode on previous install media (such as Snow Leopard came with a copy of Xcode 3), although I am not sure you will be able to install it in Lion.

Comment: I am similarly dissatisfied with final xCode 4.2. I tried the snow leopard .dmg installers. It canceled installation.